# type check dynamic properties flowtype

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to add dynamic properties to an object and have flow type check them:

my function would be like this:

```
function defineStuff(obj:MyType, keys:string[]):??? {
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {get:function(){....}});
        obj["Add"+key] = function(value) {....};
        obj["Remove"+key] = function(value) {....};
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I would like to be able to do stuff like this;

```
var obj : MyType = fetchMyObj();
defineStuff(obj, ["Thing", "OtherThing"]);
var thing = obj.Thing;
obj.AddOtherThing(10);
```

all dynamic properties type would be number

is there a syntax for doing this in flow? (i.e. how to fill the ???)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for dictionaries.

```js
type MyType = {[key: string]: number};

// ...
function defineStuff(obj: MyType, keys:string[]): MyType {
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {get:function(){....}});

        // you can't have functions here, because you say that all values should be numbers
        // obj["Add"+key] = function(value) {....};
        // obj["Remove"+key] = function(value) {....};
    }
    return obj;
}

// ...
```

[See docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)

Comment: unfortunately, MyType is not a {[string]:nuimber} dictionary, but has other stuff. only the added properties would be numbers (and corresponding functions).
I eventually gave up on that typechecking of the definitions, as I had an outer layer with the complete type (defined as an intersection type of what each component **declare** to mixin)

Comment: @MR, it looks like I misunderstood you, sorry. Anyway, what you're saying about the introducing of the "outer layer", looks like you've been forced by the FlowType to make better separation of concerns, which is a good thing after all.